# How to bind currently selected tab to a property on scope

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple tabs being displayed using ng-repeat on a collection in the scope.

Now I need a "CurrentSelection" property on the scope which should be binded to the active Tab's name. Here's the code which I am trying but it's not working, I am always getting false.

```
<uib-tab ng-repeat="mapping in template.mappings track by $index" heading="{{mapping.name}}({{mapping.targetEngineVersion}})"
                     active={{mapping.active}}>
```

Here I have written a function which tells the active tab's name:

```
private getMapping() {

    return this._scope.template.mappings.filter(function(mapping){
      return mapping.active;
    })[0];

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to have a uib-tabset and then using the active property to select the active tab.

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="mapping in template.mappings" heading="{{mapping.name}}({{mapping.targetEngineVersion}}) {{mapping.active}}" index="$index">
</uib-tabset>

 $scope.change = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.template.mappings.length; i++){
      if($scope.active === i){
        var x = 0;
        if(i+1 < $scope.template.mappings.length){
          x = i+1;
        }
        $scope.active = x;
        break;
      }
    }
  };
```

here is a link to a working example. http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/bepOOa